# Сортировка множеством

Tags: c++, stl

У меня есть некоторая неупорядоченная последовательность пар целых чисел `std::pair<int, int>`. Если все элементы этой последовательности добавить в `std::set<std::pair<int, int>> set`, гарантируется ли стандартом, что цикл `for(auto&& pair : set) std::cout << pair.first << ' ';` выдаст упорядоченную по неубыванию последовательность?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параграф 23.2.4:

> Associative containers provide fast retrieval of data based on keys.
>   The library provides four basic kinds of associative containers: set,
>   multiset, map and multimap.

Параграф 23.2.10:

> The fundamental property of iterators of associative containers is
>   that they iterate through the containers in the non-descending order
>   of keys where non-descending is deﬁned by the comparison that was used
>   to construct them.

*UPD*
Параграф 6.5.4:

> The range-based for statement for ( for-range-declaration :
>   for-range-initializer ) statement is equivalent to:

```
{
    auto &&__range = for-range-initializer ;
    auto __begin = begin-expr ;
    auto __end = end-expr ;
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin ) {
        for-range-declaration = *__begin;
        statement
    }
}
```

Версия: N4582

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно

Comment: @user248123, пожалуйста :)

Comment: Подскажите еще, если не сложно, где насчет цикла `for` по контейнеру пишут - ну, что `for(auto i: contain)` всегда работает в порядке обхода итератором (грубо говоря, `iterator++`). Просто чтоб знать :)

Comment: @Harry, обновил :)

Comment: Спасибо, почему-то этот момент в отличие от остальных мне в книгах не очень попадался. Просто писалось, что проход, очевидно, что простейший вариант именно такой, но вот что это гарантируется - почему-то не писали...

Comment: На самом деле ключевым моментом тут является именно то, что предоставляемый библиотекой оператор сравнения `<` для `std::pair` обеспечит неубывающую упорядоченность по `first`.  Однако в ответе об этом - ни слова.

Comment: @AnT, да, Вы правы. Но я видел это так: ```std::set``` обязывает нас использовать тип, с которым может работать функтор ```std::less``` (если не указано иного), а далее - все вышесказанное Вами относительно ```std::pair```.

Answer (score 2):

Да

у типа `std::pair<...>` перегружен оператор `<` который сравнивает сперва `std::pair::first` элементы (если они равны то уже вторые сравниваются), поэтому всё отработает как и ожидалось - в выводе будет отсортированно по не убыванию

```
std::set<std::pair<int, int>> mySet;

mySet.insert({ 5, -1 });
mySet.insert({ 3, 4 });
mySet.insert({ 4, 1 });
mySet.insert({ 2, 2 });
mySet.insert({ 1, 2 });

for (auto && p : mySet)
{
    cout << p.first << '\n';
}
```

**p.s.**

Только не забудьте, что при наличии одинаковых первых значений в `set` такие дубликаты не попадут

Comment: То что оператор есть, это понятно. Но почему `mySet.begin()` обязательно выведет минимальный элемент, `std::next(mySet.begin())` - второй, и т.д.? Ведь реализация может быть разной, и как хранятся элементы неизвестно

Comment: @user248123 `set` это упорядоченное множество уникальных элементов (а если углубится то этот контейнер основан на красно-чёрном дереве)

Comment: мы же не знаем, как это дерево хранится + не обязательно там дерево

Comment: @user248123 для `std::set` почти все реализации `stl` используют красно-чёрное дерево, или любое другое бинарное сбалансированное двоичное дерево поиска

Comment: мне интересны гарантии стандарта